# how to validate one specific form's fields among different forms under a Parent form

Tags: forms, validation

If you see on the attachment, I have 3 different forms under a single form with same submit. The top two form's fields already validate but now I would like to validate the fields of the Rechnung form so that at least it should not have empty fields. I tried with HTML5 'required' and some other js/jquery but all are affecting the other two forms too.

How can I only check on fly the fields with Rechnung form?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:
validates_association :rechnungs

Comment: Can you add some more info , e.g. post your form please and the model with the validation? Thx. What exactly do you mean by on fly validation?

Comment: Actually all the form sharing the same submit => form.get(0).submit(); I need some short of way to check form validation only for the #invoice-form. @  KcUS_unico